# Is it possible to get the log data of a smart contract?

Tags: logs

I would like to know if it's possible to get the log data of a smart contract. The thing is that I need to get the adress, the tokenId and a couple more variables, but I don't know how to get that information once the contract is already deployed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "log data"? Are you talking about logged events? Those can be found in the transaction receipt.

Comment: Let me explain it. When I deploy the contract I emit an event, but I can't access to it directly to get the information. cause I don't know how actually. So I need a way that allows me to deploy the contract and then get the information about it.

Comment: I did actually notice that Hardhat has a `console.log(..)` function, but I think you need to use the Hardhat framework to make the tx calls and be able to view those logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare variable as public after you get variable data via simple web3 call of that function.

Comment: I'll try it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As Akshay has said, you can simply make variables public to read from the contract later, but you can also read events from the transaction receipt.

An example using ethersjs:
Test.sol

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract Test {
    event TestEvent(uint256 data);

    constructor() {
        emit TestEvent(123);
    }
}
```

deploy.js

```js
const Test = await ethers.getContractFactory('Test');
let test = await Test.deploy();
test = await test.deployed();
let receipt = await test.deployTransaction.wait();
let events = receipt.events;

let testEvent = events.filter(({event}) => event == 'TestEvent')[0];
console.log(testEvent.args.data);
```

```
>> BigNumber { value: "123" }
```